# two tab switching in one page not working

Tags: javascript, tabs, jscript

I want to create two tab switching independent to each other in one page. This code here only allows tab switching one at a time and the content of the other tab that is not active is hidden.

**HTML:**

```
//FIRST TAB
    <ul id="tab">
       <li>OPTION 1</li>
       <li class="select">OPTION 2</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content_wrap disnon">
      <p><a href="#">●●●●●111</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">●●●●●222</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="content_wrap">
      <p><a href="#">●●●●●111</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">●●●●●222</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">●●●●●333</a></p>
    </div>

//SECOND
    <ul id="tab">
       <li class="select">OPTION A</li>
       <li>OPTION B</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content_wrap">
      <p><a href="#">●●●●●AAA</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">●●●●●BBB</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">●●●●●CCC</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">●●●●●DDD</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="content_wrap disnon">
      <p><a href="#">●●●●●AAA</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">●●●●●BBB</a></p>
    </div>
```

**JScript:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#tab li").click(function() {
        var num = $("#tab li").index(this);
        $(".content_wrap").addClass('disnon');
        $(".content_wrap").eq(num).removeClass('disnon');
        $("#tab li").removeClass('select');
        $(this).addClass('select')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to check here first.

1. Both of these tabs have the same id. ID's are supposed to be unique, say tab1 and tab2.
2. It would be better if you could show us the css of this file.

However if my assumption is correct that 
tab1 -> click -> show tab1 content AND
tab2 -> click -> show tab2 content.
The code is as follows.

```
// USING EITHER HTML5 DATA TAGS OR INDIVIDUAL ID'S
<ul class="tab" data-tab="1"> ... </ul>
<ul class="tab" data-tab="2"> ... </ul>

<div id="tabContent1" class="tabContent"></div>
<div id="tabContent2" class="tabContent" style="display:none"></div> 
// SET NOT TO DISPLAY WHEN FIRST ACTIVE

<script>
$('.tab').on('click',function() {
    // SELECT CLICKED TAB'S DATA (ie 1 / 2) IN THIS CASE
    var tab = $(this).data('tab');
    // HIDE ALL OTHER tabContent
    $('.tabContent').hide();
    // SHOW ONE TAB
    $('#tabContent' + tab).show();
});
```

This has been simplified to easily be expandable for more than one tab. Simply adding more uls & divs will easily create a tab switching layout.